# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay blocks the ui thread

Tags: ios, selector

I want to perform an action (setting button enabled state) on the ui thread

however, if i want to perform it "After delay" it seems to block the ui thread

```
-(void)changeButtonState:(UIButton *)btn{
   [btn setEnabled:NO];

   [self performSelector:@selector(reenableButton:) withObject:btn afterDelay:5];

}

-(void)reenableButton:(UIButton*)btn{
    [btn setEnabled:YES];
}
```

how can i perform a selector after delay, without it blocking the main thread, and the operation i need to do must be done on the ui thread ?

Comment: `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` does not block the current thread. Are you saying that you UI is blocked for 5 seconds until the selector is called? That should not be happening at all.

Comment: I have 2 edit texts on the screen and a button, after inputting some input in the first edit text, i click the button, which in turn becomes disabled, i am not able to click on the second edit text to change its value before the button becomes reenabled. i have written it so pressing on the screen outside any views (edit fields, buttons) hides the keyboard, that doesnt happen while the button is disabled

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your got your outlets wrong. Perhaps you've made an outlet to the underlying view instead of to the button.

If this is the case, then you should get a warning something like this: `Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIView *' to parameter of type 'UIButton *'`

This would explain why everything gets disabled, and not just the button.